# undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass in custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thereis the following model:

```
class TimeCorrection < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :start_time, :end_time, :value, presence: true

    validate :time_comparison

    def time_comparison
        errors[:base] << 'Incorrect end time' if start_time > end_time
    end
end
```

I've got error about Nil if end_time or start_time are Nil. How can I fit? How to execute time_comparison validation only if the previous validation is correctly?

Comment: start_time has `nil`, but anyway could you use `validates_presence :start_time, :end_time, :value` line instead of thou hast specifed?

Comment: I don't understand you, sorry

Comment: replace `validates :start_time, :end_time, :value, presence: true` with `validates_presence :start_time, :end_time, :value`. then rebuild db structure avoiding all errors during migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class TimeCorrection < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :start_time, :end_time, :value, presence: true

    validate :time_comparison

    def time_comparison
        errors[:base] << 'Incorrect end time' if start_time && end_time && start_time > end_time
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, You have to check if start and end time are not nil:

```
def time_comparison
    errors[:base] << 'Incorrect end time' if start_time && end_time && start_time > end_time
end
```